# Can C++ references be extended for more than one variable?

Tags: c++

If we have the following lines in our code

```
int a=6, c=1;
int& b=a;
```

Then what impact will

```
(int&) b=c
```

have on the value of c?

Comment: So is this a C++ or C question?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie `C` has references?

Comment: What impact on the value of `c`? None? The code has undefined behaviour anyway.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @BoBTFish no it doesn't, but the question says "C style cast" so why relate to C++ using C style cast?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie: Because you can cast C-Style in C++? If it wasn't C++ it would just be a cast - and wouldn't compile.

Comment: @woz: No. I am sure that future changes of either b or a won't have any affect on c. but then to explain the difference between `b=c` and `(int&) b=c` was difficult so I decided to post hoping for an explanation.

Comment: @sjsam What is that "difficult to explain" difference? And why didn't you just ask "what difference is there between `(int& b)` and `b` if `b` has been declared as `int& b`"?

Comment: @DanielDaranas: The implied idea was will C++ references move around for more than one variables.. Wasn't able to convey it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b` is already a `int&` - you declared it as such. So `(int&) b` is the same as `b`. **Your cast doesn't make any sense.** It is the same as `b = c;` (after adding the semicolon you missed).

C++ references don't move around refering to several variables - they always refer to the variable they were initialized to. So **`b = c;` will have no present or future effect on `c`**.

Actually, though, your code has **undefined behaviour**, because for some reason you fail to initialize your variable `c` and then you use its value.

If your first line had been `int a = 0, c = 1;` so that you avoid undefined behaviour, then the effect of your code would be to assign `1` (the value of `c`) to `a` (and, of course, to its alias `b`).

Comment: Thank You. Exactly the answer I was looking for. All the initialization stuff were made when I had a test run. I missed it when putting the question.